# MySQL Trigger on after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to MySQL. I have two tables `total_loaner` and `available_loaner`. I am trying to create a trigger for every new row added in `total_loaner`, I would also like to add that new row to `available_loaner`.

Here how my tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `total_loaner` (
  `Kind` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Sno` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sno`)
)

CREATE TABLE `available_loaner` (
  `Kind` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Sno` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Status` char(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sno`)
)
```

My trigger does not seem to work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_loaner_added 
AFTER INSERT ON 'total_loaner' for each row
begin
INSERT INTO available_loaner (Kind, Type, Sno, Status)
Values (new.Kind, new.Type, new.Sno, 'Available');
END;
```

Answer (score 32):

In your case you can rewrite your trigger like this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER new_loaner_added 
AFTER INSERT ON total_loaner
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO available_loaner (Kind, Type, Sno, Status)
  VALUES (NEW.Kind, NEW.Type, NEW.Sno, 'Available');
```

**Note:**

- single quotes removed from table name `total_loaner`, because quotes effectively makes it a string literal instead of a proper identifier. You can use back ticks if you want but it's unnecessary since it's not a reserved word and it don't contain any special characters.
- since it's a one-statement trigger now you don't need to use `DELIMITER` command and `BEGIN...END` block

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d97d/1)** demo

Answer (score 9):

You probably need to set your delimiter:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER new_loaner_added 
AFTER INSERT ON `total_loaner` for each row
begin
INSERT INTO available_loaner (Kind, Type, Sno, Status)
Values (new.Kind, new.Type, new.Sno, 'Available');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Right now, it's confusing the semi-colon at the end of the `INSERT` statement with the end of the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

Answer (score 6):

This one worked for me, more simplified version..

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_loaner_added 
    AFTER INSERT ON `DB1`.`table_name`
    FOR EACH ROW 
      INSERT INTO `DB2`.`table_name` (messageID, conversationID, fromJID)
      VALUES (NEW.messageID,NEW.conversationID, NEW.fromJID);
```

Comment: and if another table column names are different then what we should do?

Answer (score 0):

```
AFTER INSERT ON `total_loaner`
```

Use backticks.