# Unique code generation using Last Insert Id in Code Igniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to create a **drcode** using the last insert id in the prescribed format,
previously I have used cor php to get the code but now in codeigniter am not able to get the code as the previous one. How can i do this? I am providing my controller and model

**Controller**

```
public function newdoctor_post() {
            $employee_id = $this->post('EMPLOYEE_ID');
            $doctorname = $this->post('DOCTOR_NAME');
            $mobilenumber = $this->post('DRMOBILE');
            $users_data = $this->Rest_user_model->doctor_exists($mobilenumber);
            if ($users_data == 1) {
                $message = ['status' => 2,
                // 'result' => array(),
                'message' => 'Doctor already registered'];
            } else {
                $speciality = $this->post('SPECIALITY');
                $longitude = $this->post('LONGITUDE');
                $latitude = $this->post('LATITUDE');
                $drcode = $this->post('DRCODE');
                $createdon = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $insert_array = array('EMPLOYEE_ID' => $employee_id, 'DOCTOR_NAME' => $doctorname, 'DRMOBILE' => $mobilenumber, 'SPECIALITY' => $speciality, 'LONGITUDE' => $longitude, 'LATITUDE' => $latitude, 'CREATEDON' => $createdon);
                $users_data = $this->Rest_user_model->doctorregistration($insert_array);
                $message = ['status' => 1, // 'result' => $users_data,
                'message' => 'Doctor Registered Successfully'];
            }
            $this->set_response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        }
```

**Model**

```
public function doctorregistration($data) {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $this->db->insert('DOCTORDETAILS', $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

**Code Generation**

```
$sql1="SELECT DRCODE FROM DOCTORDETAILS  ORDER BY DRCODEDESC LIMIT 1";
    $query=mysql_query($sql1);
    if (!$sql1) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $output_array2=array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $ids=$row['DRCODE'];

    }
    // echo $ids;
    if($ids){
        $su=1;
        $num =$num = 'DR' . str_pad($su + substr($ids, 3), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);;
        $unique=$num;
    }else{
        $unique='DR000001';     
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - replace this code below with your Code Generation code.

```
$sql1="SELECT DRCODE FROM DOCTORDETAILS  ORDER BY DRCODEDESC LIMIT 1";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql1);
    if (!$sql1) { // add this check.
        die('Invalid query');
    }
    $output_array2=array();
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $ids=$row['DRCODE'];
    }
    // echo $ids;
    if($ids){
        $su=1;
        $num =$num = 'DR' . str_pad($su + substr($ids, 3), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);;
        $unique=$num;
    }else{
        $unique='DR000001';     
    }
```

Comment: I need to implement this in Codeigniter @TigerTiger while implementing it doesnot give any value

Comment: Yes I did that for you. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a different column fr drcode, leave it blank.
Now make a trigger on insert, it should be run after insert.

I am assuming DOCTORDETAILS as table name and drcode as column name

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_after_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON `DOCTORDETAILS` FOR EACH ROW
begin

UPDATE `DOCTORDETAILS` set drcode=CONCAT('DR',new.id);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger create a new string with your new auto generated id

> Trigger in MySQL:
>
> [TechonTheNet](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php)
>
> [MySQL Trigger on after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728539/mysql-trigger-on-after-insert)

Comment: @SairamDuggi yes we can but you need to execute one more query after insert. We are doing same as I am suggested.

Comment: Can't update table 'doctordetails' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger I have got this error @Irfan

Comment: I have update the answer, also check does any trigger already use for the table

Comment: It says the we cannot do insert and update on the same table @Irfan