# Finding possible options for commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found by coincidence that there is an option after for the command add_column in rails. I was interested in knowing what other options are available, but searching the internet I was not able to find a place where the possible options for this command are listed.

Does anybody have a tip, how I could find such information?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The options are described in the online documentation. For example, check the [API docks for column](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_column). If you read carefully, it clearly gives another link that describes the options. I found this quickly using Google.

Comment: Could you please explain how I have to read this carefully. I went through each of the links of the "API docks for column" page and in none of them I found any mention of the "after" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to refer to the documentation.  In this case you probably just want to see:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column

Update, if you're referring to a database specific option such as [MySql after option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728539/mysql-trigger-on-after-insert#18729664), refer to [Rails ActiveRecord model callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) instead as this is more universal and should work regardless of which DB you chose.

Comment: I am really sorry that I did not say what I had already done before writing my inquiry. I already went through that link and found no mention of the "after" option.

Answer (score 0):

There's usually `ri` and `rdoc` documentation installed within a gem.
You're probably looking for that.

In the terminal (not `irb` or `rails c`, just terminal) execute the following command:

```
ri add_column
```

And you'll get the docs for this specific method.

You might receive `Nothing known about ActiveRecord::Migration` at first. It can fixed by running `rvm docs generate` command.

If you're using Rails 4, in order to view the details of the options you can use, you might want to run:

```
ri column
```

Comment: This doesn't tell you what options are available, only that the options hash can be passed as an argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint. Unfortunately there is not much information available when I execute that command: This is the output:

= .add_column

(from gem activerecord-4.2.8)
=== Implementation from SchemaStatements
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  add_column(table_name, column_name, type, options = {})

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Adds a new column to the named table. See TableDefinition#column for details
of the options you can use.

Comment: @DarkerWing The message actually told you to see TableDefinition#column for details of the options you can use. What did stop you from running `ri column`?

Comment: @Igor Just my ignorance. I had tried with with TableDefinition#column :-( Though even with "ri column" there is no mention of the "after" option. I assume now that this is not a rails code option but a MySQL code option. In fact I could find the option in the MySQL manuals. So I presume using the after option is not database agnosic and therefore bad coding style