# Is there any way to execute a PHP Page or URL using sql query or sql trigger at insert?

Tags: php, mysql, execute

Actually i have implemented something by which i am getting data from some outside source into my database table, and now want to add some trigger at insert time, that will fire my Php page code , that php code is having some logic that fires SMS. So as soon as i got data into my sql table i want to fire / execute my php page to send sms autometically. But I don't know how to use sql to execute a url or php page. Please help in this matter.

I am thinking like , When data will inserted by some third party into my db table , then trigger will run some stored procedure , that stored procedure will execute a php page and then automatically my task will done.

Select php-url from lead_table where id=5 
EXEC php-url 
END-EXEC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Trigger on after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728539/mysql-trigger-on-after-insert)

Comment: Better approach: use php to get the data, update database, and send sms. How *are* you getting data into you database?

Answer (score 1):

Using api I was receiving the data from third party like this insert_new.php?name=vibhor&add=abc etc. Then i was inserting into the data base table. My thinking was wrong to execute php page from sql table. Actually my code was creating the sql row, so i used the same variables that i was passing in insert query and then i pass those variable to other send sms php page using curl. And hence I am able to send the sms instantly and automatically... This solved my problem. I edited my code in insert_new.php and everything works great :)